# Angular 9 Reactive forms On submit reloading the route

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing, angular-reactive-forms, json-server

I am creating reactive form in Angular 9. I have few fields like first name, last name, email etc. I mapped every thing using form builder, form control name both in html and ts. And I am using ng Submit to submit the form and i didn't give any button type(since by default it will take as submit type). I am trying to save the data in JSON file. after that I am subscribing to the result.  But when I am trying to navigate to another route in subscribe(), every time the page is reloading.  it is navigating and NOT reloading  when  I am not subscribing.

I am using JSON-Server to save the data in JSON file.

Could you please help me how to prevent this? Thanks in Advance :)

Here is the code.
[image]

.ts file

[image]

service.ts
[image]

Comment: Please provide your code samples not as an image. Also try to provide a working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: I am trying to add stackbltiz. But meanwhile Could you please clone this repo? https://github.com/HariPogula/Employee-CRUD.git and please run npm run dev:local after npm install

Comment: I found the solution.The problem is with json-server library. When we add/update/delete in json file using  angular service, it will RELOAD the browser. So we can stop reloading by using ng serve option " --live-reload=false". But only drawback is every time we need to run the ng serve.